# Pages are not displaying properly in Internet Explorer 8 even using bootstrap3

Tags: internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've developed website using `bootstrap 3`.

The pages are displaying properly in `Chrome` and `Firefox` but not in `Internet Explorer 8`.

Are there any css or js files have to be included?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to [the Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers):

> Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are also supported, however, please be aware that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported by these browsers. **In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to enable media query support.**